# After installing docker on centos7,Failed to start docker."Job for docker.service failed."

Tags: docker, centos7

After executing `yum install docker` on **centos7**, I want to start docker by executing `service docker start`, then i can see the error:

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  docker.service
>   Job for docker.service failed. See 'systemctl status docker.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

then I execute `systemctl status docker.service -l`, then the error is:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-03-15 03:49:49 EDT; 12min ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 11444 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11444 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Mar 15 03:49:48 localhost.localdomain docker[11444]: 2015/03/15 03:49:48 docker daemon: 1.3.2 39fa2fa/1.3.2; execdriver: native; graphdriver:
Mar 15 03:49:48 localhost.localdomain docker[11444]: [a25f748b] +job serveapi(fd://)
Mar 15 03:49:48 localhost.localdomain docker[11444]: [info] Listening for HTTP on fd ()
Mar 15 03:49:48 localhost.localdomain docker[11444]: [a25f748b] +job init_networkdriver()
Mar 15 03:49:48 localhost.localdomain docker[11444]: [a25f748b] -job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)
Mar 15 03:49:49 localhost.localdomain docker[11444]: 2015/03/15 03:49:49 write /var/lib/docker/init/dockerinit-1.3.2: no space left on device
Mar 15 03:49:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 15 03:49:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 15 03:49:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
```

I really have no idea, looking forward to your response, I will be very appreciative!

Comment: The error `no space left on device` may indicate a full filesystem. Have you check how much disk space you have available to `/var/lib/docker`?

Comment: This [Github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15498) suggests that `yum install docker-io-selinux` would fix the problem if you have selinux enabled

Answer (score 2):

this error usually occurs because of missing device-mapper-event-libs package.

```
# yum install device-mapper-event-libs
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for **Ben Whaley**'s advice,When I check my disk space,Indeed it's not enough.I extend my disk space and solve the problem. It's the first time I put forward questions,It's really of help. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the CentOS 7 kernel from 3 to 4.

**NOTE: I upgraded Kernel for other reasons also, first try without upgrading kernel.**

1. delete the  folder docker  under /var/lib
2. go to cd /etc/sysconfig
3. vi docker (before editing copy docker docker.org)
4. see Line there you find OPTIONS='--selinux-disabled --log-driver=journald'
5. Remove --selinux-disabled  should like OPTIONS='--log-driver=journald'
6. Now un-comment # setsebool -P docker_transition_unconfined 1 to setsebool -P docker_transition_unconfined 1
7. reboot the machine or you try only docker start to check for me it works :)